# StartForeground Bad notification Android 2.3.X

Tags: android, service, android-notifications, foreground

I'm having a bug report, for some android device with version 2.3.X :

android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Here's my method...

```
final static int myID = 6785674;

public void putServiceToForeground() {
    if (notif == null) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyApp.getAppContext())
        .setContentTitle("");
        notif = mBuilder.build();
        notif.icon = R.drawable.pixel;
    }
    startForeground(myID, notif);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Builder to set the icon and also double check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateNotification).

> ### Required notification contents
>
> A Notification object must contain the following:
>
> - A small icon, set by setSmallIcon()
> - A title, set by setContentTitle()
> - Detail text, set by setContentText()